# Django: socket doesn't seem to connect without returning any errors

Tags: python, django, websocket, async-await, django-channels

My name is Liran and I am currently working on my computer science final project.

My project is a web based ide with the main selling point of a room feature in which a couple of people can work on the same code together. for the backend I am using python - Django and for the frontend I am using JS and bootstrap for the design.

At first I wanted to just create a basic html page in which I can write some text into a text-area and for every new input to the text area the server would get notified and update everyone via the socket and when someone pressed the submit button the code will run on the server and the output is returned real time (I know the security risks and how not smart it is to do that I just need a fast way to do it for my project). After getting a fully skeleton of the project (you can see the working skeleton of the project in the `dev` branch in the GitHub page) I started making a way to create "rooms" in which people can work together in a custom socket. For this I had to make the code for the socket way more dynamic so I had to rewrite most of it using the async/await keywords and making the routing of the socket and the project views 100% dynamic. Right now everything is looking fine I can create new pages and work inside of them.. I even started working on the front end.. but when I went back to check if I can compile code or even see the text updating in the text area I am getting no response and no socket errors.. I have tried changing the way to socket is routed and stuff but right now it still doesn't seem to work.. if someone has any suggestion I would like to hear:

this is the github page of my project: https://github.com/LiranBratt2121/webide

go to the dev branch to see the server actually communicating with the client `docs/ide` - page
go to the the link-sys branch to see the updated code: `/home/`

things that I tried:

I tried reverting back the synchronous but it had a lot of problem thanks to how to code of the rooms is constructed. So I decided to go back to async code

I also tried messing around with the routing of the project and to try and create errors to debug and solve the main error - because right now I don't get any socket error.

consumers.py:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
    self.slug = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['slug']
    self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.slug   
    self.process = None
    self.thread = None
    self.output = ''

    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
    await self.accept()
```

---

routing.py:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'ws/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

]

---

js socket part in ide.html:

```
  {{ project.slug|json_script:"json-projectname" }}

  <script type="text/javascript">
const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-projectname').textContent); 

let url = "ws://" + window.location.host.toString() + "/ws/" + roomName + "/"

const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url);
```

---

(new project view) views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def project_ide(request, slug):
project = get_object_or_404(Room, slug=slug)
return render(request, 'docs/ide.html', {'project': project})
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).